# Ralink RT3573 chipset not working with Ralink linux driver for that chipset. What now?

Tags: drivers, usb, internet, ralink, adapter

So I have a netgear n900 usb adapter I wanted to use to obtain a wireless connection in the latest ubuntu system.  I followed some instructions that I will post below in order to download a Ralink driver for linux and make it.  I called Netgear to make sure that the chipset in the usb netowrk adapter is indeed the ralink RT3573.  It is.

Once I made the driver, the light on my usb adapter turned on and the networks in my range appeared.  I selected my network, entered the WAP password and pressed connect, it cycles through but never connects, and then asks for the password again.  It will do this ad infinitum without ever connecting.  So what do I need to do to secure the connection?

I am unsure if there is a problem with the driver or if it is related to network manager and a brand new update to Ubuntu 12.10.  When I type in iwconfig this is the output:

```
ra0       Ralink STA  ESSID:"11n-AP"  Nickname:"RT2870STA"
          Mode:Auto  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Bit Rate:1 Mb/s   
          RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Link Quality=100/100  Signal level:-67 dBm  Noise level:-85 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

Lsusb returns this:

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0846:9012 NetGear, Inc. WNDA4100 802.11abgn 3x3:3 [Ralink RT3573]

Below is how I made the driver:
Props to Chili555 who originally gave these instructions here: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2089469.html

except I had to tweak them some since the website where you get the driver has changed and the name of the folder extracted has since changed as well.

You will need to download RT3573 USB here: 
http://www.mediatek.com/_en/07_downloads/01-1_windowsDetail.php?sn=5034

Drag and drop it to your desktop. Right-click it and select Extract Here. Now we need to modify two files. 

Navigate to os > linux (you can also open home folder and click search and then type in the file names) and open the file config.mk with a text editor such as gedit (right-click > open with text editor). Be certain these lines are set to =y:
# Support Wpa_Supplicant
# i.e. wpa_supplicant -Dralink
HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT=y


# Support Native WpaSupplicant for Network Maganger
# i.e. wpa_supplicant -Dwext
HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=y

Proofread, save and close the text editor. Now navigate to common and open rtusb_dev_id.c with a text editor. Make the change I've highlighted here:

#endif /* RT35xx */
#ifdef RT3573
{USB_DEVICE(0x148F,0x3573)}, /* Ralink 3573 */
{USB_DEVICE(0x7392,0x7733)}, /* Edimax */
{USB_DEVICE(0x0846,0x9012)}, /* Netgear */
{USB_DEVICE(0x0B05,0x17AD)}, /*ASUS */
#endif /* RT3573 */
{ }/* Terminating entry */
```

All you are doing is adding the highlighted part. All else is unchanged. Punctuation, spacing, brackets, etc. is crucial and must be exact. Proofread, save and close the text editor.

Now we install the necessary build tools:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic

Now we compile the driver:
cd ./Desktop/20120911_RT3573_Linux_STA_v2.5.0.0_Rev1_DPO    
sudo su
make
make install
modprobe rt3573sta
exit
```

Your device should now be working.

Except it isn't, what do I do?